# why iOS7 simulator doesn't start or start as it wants...?

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

After getting many issues in starting the iOS 7 simulator ( tried many of the posted suggestions around there ... including reinstalling XCode5 ..
I am trying now to run THE Apple HelloWorld sample .. which SHOULD be THE test reference..

first build .. it runs on the simulator
however once can see a lot of errors in the simulator console, including a malformed bunlde one...

extracted from the simulator console log at https://gist.github.com/erwin/7230844

```
Oct 30 08:26:37 macMini profiled[1456] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Waiting for DataMigrator...
Oct 30 08:26:40 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Oct 30 08:26:40 macMini SpringBoard[1460] <Error>: objc[1460]: Class AXEmojiUtilities is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libAXSpeechManager.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 30 08:26:40 macMini com.apple.iphonesimulator.launchd.7e32645e[1451] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SpringBoard.1460) <Error>: Failed to bootstrap path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudServices.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.lakitu.xpc
    error: 107: Malformed bundle
Oct 30 08:26:41 macMini profiled[1456] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Waiting for DataMigrator...
```

but at least it's running...

obviously this sample has not been updated .... so I get the warning

```
Oct 30 08:51:26 macMini HelloWorld[1792] <Warning>: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

and I modified the code in consequence, adding the root view controller

```
[window addSubview:controllersView];
[window setRootViewController:myViewController];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I clean the Xcode product, I cleared and reset the simulator, then I closed it ..
new build and run ... the simulator open , but doesn't run the HelloWorld app...

I don't see any failure in the simulator console log at https://gist.github.com/erwin/7230768 
but nothing happen , simulator seems to be lost in the air....
and no clear explanation on HOW TO MAKE IT RUNNING CORRECTLY from Apple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might also be an incomplete or corrupted installation. I would wipe and re-install, then try to compile and run the sample without changing anything. (I would hope that the sample (or first sample) should at least compile and run OK on the simulator.)

Comment: that's it... corrupted installation.  After re-installing XCode5 and simulators ( SDK 6.1 and 7) running fine now ...

Answer (score 1):

You might have had an incomplete update of some core functionality. With Apple keeping everything so closed down, it's hard to do any real diagnoses. If you haven't already, I'd take it to an Apple "genius" (their terminology, not being sarcastic), they'll probably recommend wiping it and starting again.